# Bintray Gradle Plugin - POM is incomplete, won't sync to Maven Central?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, bintray

I have been trying to get an artifact automatically deployed for weeks to Bintray and to sync with Maven Central, all within the Travis build system.

I was able to upload to Bintray, but the sync to Maven Central keeps failing because it complains about the POM missing stuff. Here is the output log:

https://travis-ci.org/ReactiveX/RxJavaFX/builds/459139577

And here is the relevant parts of the Gradle script.

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJavaFX/blob/2.11.x/build.gradle#L83-L156

It's weird because I have declared the POM and it's constructed just fine locally, but the Bintray deployment produces a bare-bones POM:

https://dl.bintray.com/reactivex/RxJava/io/reactivex/rxjava2/rxjavafx/2.11.0-RC32/

Can somebody please provide guidance with what I'm missing? I'm sorry I'm a complete newb with automated artifact deployments, especially when it's owned by an organization I don't have the keys to.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the Travis log you can see

> Project name missing, Project description missing, Project URL missing, License information missing, SCM URL missing, Developer information missing, Invalid POM: /io/reactivex/rxjava2/rxjavafx/2.11.0-RC31/rxjavafx-2.11.0-RC31.pom: Project name missing, Project description missing, Project URL missing, License information missing, SCM URL missing, Developer information missing, Missing: no javadoc jar found in folder

Maven Central has many more requirements than bintray, I suggest you look through the minimum requirements [here](https://central.sonatype.org/pages/requirements.html)